# How to get current user on a multi site that is using domain mapping?

Tags: users

When I use the following code on a single blog site it works but if fails on a multi site that uses the domain mapping plugin. This code is in a plugin that is called by a short code.

`global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user = wp_get_current_user();`

$current_user is empty. Any ideas?

Update: I found a similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163407/get-current-user-id-returns-0) that said the init had to run first. I did test for this condition and the init had run before this code is called.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by first checking if the user was logged in using: is_user_logged_in().